# Origin of different network timeouts?

Tags: networking, kernel

Linux uses 20 seconds as default tcp connect timeout.

- What is the reason for this specific timeout value?

Note: I'm researching a data-driving approach to configuring socket timeouts in a specific client. I have noticed different systems (linux, bsd, windows) do not standardize on default timeout value. I am curious if there is rationale behind the long timeouts when arguably most networks under standard operating conditions require orders of magnitude less time to establish a connection.

Comment: Vaguely related classic story: [the case of the 500-mile email](https://www.ibiblio.org/harris/500milemail.html).

Comment: @Wildcard a classic (=